# Why results of stepGAICAll.A() function of GAMLSS package are different when it is used within a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, gamlss

I would like to know why when I use **stepGAICAll.A()** function within a `for-loop` gives different results compared with those obtained when I use it without a for-loop (of course, setting the same function arguments).

The data used for explaining the problem can be loaded after gamlss package is loaded:

```
library(gamlss)
data('dbhh')
df <- dbhh[1:100,] # this is a subset for simplifying calculations
dfm <- transform(df, lage=log(age), lht=log(ht))
head(dfm)
```

The new data frame `dfm` is as follows:

```
  head  age   ht      lage      lht
1 33.6 0.03 53.3 -3.506558 3.975936
2 33.6 0.04 50.8 -3.218876 3.927896
3 33.7 0.04 50.1 -3.218876 3.914021
4 35.0 0.04 53.5 -3.218876 3.979682
5 36.1 0.04 52.1 -3.218876 3.953165
6 36.6 0.05 50.5 -2.995732 3.921973
```

***First case: using stepGAICAll.A() without a for-loop***

If I specify one distribution (in this case “BCTo”) and apply **stepGAICAll.A()** function:

```
options(warn=1)
nC <- 4 # this is the number of CPU cores
m0_1 <- gamlss(head ~ 1, data=dfm, family=BCTo, n.cyc=800) #mu.start=30, sigma.start=1, nu.start=1, tau.start=1
model_1 <- stepGAICAll.A(m0_1, 
                          scope=list(lower = ~ 1, upper = ~ lage + lht),  
                          k=2, parallel='multicore', ncpus=nC)
```

the results (after executing `summary(model_1)`) are as follows:

```
******************************************************************
Family:  c("BCTo", "Box-Cox-t-orig.") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = head ~ lht + lage, sigma.formula = ~lht,  
    nu.formula = ~1, tau.formula = ~lage + lht, family = BCTo,  
    data = dfm, n.cyc = 800, trace = FALSE) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  log
Mu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.84363    0.12370   14.90  < 2e-16 ***
lht          0.48800    0.03058   15.96  < 2e-16 ***
lage         0.06683    0.01208    5.53 3.04e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   24.208     11.098   2.181   0.0317 *
lht           -7.007      2.797  -2.506   0.0140 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Nu link function:  identity 
Nu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -5.857      4.086  -1.434    0.155

------------------------------------------------------------------
Tau link function:  log 
Tau Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   71.058     71.051   1.000    0.320
lage          -7.393      6.707  -1.102    0.273
lht          -21.912     16.311  -1.343    0.183

------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  100 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  9
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  91 
                      at cycle:  8 
 
Global Deviance:     287.9476 
            AIC:     305.9476 
            SBC:     329.3941 
******************************************************************
```

***Second case: using stepGAICAll.A() within a for-loop***

If I try the same for a group of distributions, including “BCTo”

```
pdf_2 <- c('BCTo', 'BCPEo')
m0_2 <- list()
model_2 <- list()
n_2 <- length(pdf_2)
for (i in 1:n_2) {
    m0_2[[pdf_2[i]]] <- gamlss(head ~ 1, data=dfm, family=pdf_2[i], n.cyc=800) #mu.start=30, sigma.start=1, nu.start=1, tau.start=1
    model_2[[pdf_2[i]]] <- stepGAICAll.A(m0_2[[pdf_2[i]]], 
                          scope = list(lower = ~ 1, 
                                       upper = ~ lage + lht), 
                          k=2, parallel='multicore', ncpus=nC)
}
```

then results (after executing `summary(model_2[['BCTo']])`) differ regarding the previously calculated using only “BCTo”:

```
******************************************************************
Family:  c("BCTo", "Box-Cox-t-orig.") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = head ~ lht + lage, sigma.formula = ~lht,  
    nu.formula = ~1, tau.formula = ~lage, family = pdf_2[i],  
    data = dfm, n.cyc = 800, trace = FALSE) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  log
Mu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.82189    0.66376   2.745 0.007281 ** 
lht          0.49403    0.15754   3.136 0.002301 ** 
lage         0.06760    0.01841   3.671 0.000405 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   16.743     11.644   1.438   0.1539  
lht           -5.129      2.930  -1.750   0.0834 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
Nu link function:  identity 
Nu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -6.498     10.255  -0.634    0.528

------------------------------------------------------------------
Tau link function:  log 
Tau Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -22.819     32.273  -0.707    0.481
lage          -9.804     12.998  -0.754    0.453

------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  100 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  8
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  92 
                      at cycle:  7 
 
Global Deviance:     290.2502 
            AIC:     306.2502 
            SBC:     327.0916 
******************************************************************
```

In this second case only the variable `lage` was selected by **stepGAICAll.A()** for modeling the tau parameter (see `tau.formula = ~lage`), while in the first case `lage` and `lht` were selected (`tau.formula = ~lage + lht`). I do not understand why this happens if *all the function arguments are exactly the same for both cases*. The **gamlss()** function also has arguments that allow to set initial values for the distribution parameters, but if they are used (e.g. `mu.start=30`, `sigma.start=1`, `nu.start=1`, `tau.start=1`) then results also differ.

I would appreciate some help or comments. Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. I hope my explanation be understood. I apologize for my English, I am still learning.

Comment: If the question is “what is the best way to find an optimal numerical solution “ then it’s more a question for stats.stackexchange.com. If it’s how to deal with an error in a for loop, then it’s on topic but I think we would need a [MCVE] and I don’t see one. Questions about error with no data will be closed as not reproducible and lacking needed details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @IRTFM. The data can be loaded after gamlss package is loaded. I mean: 1) library(gamlss) and then 2) data('dbhh'). This data frame has 3 variables: "head", "age" and "ht". The example can be reproduced copying the code showed in the post. Regarding what is the point of the question, I would like to know why when I use stepGAICAll.A() function within a for-loop gives different results compared with those obtained when I use it without a for-loop (of course, setting the same function arguments).

Comment: It now appears to have an MCVE. It's quite a compute load and runs slowly but does run (after initially hanging my machine.)

Comment: I can replicate the results from `model_1`, but it took so long to run on my machine that I'm unmotivated to run an even longer set of models. I do know that non-linear methods  numerical methods may arrive at different results when the starting values of estimated parameters are are varied.

Comment: Thank you for your time @IRTFM. I have modified the post (adding more details) and code for reducing the computation time.

Comment: So far there's only my reopen vote. The code runs _much_ faster and when I compare  console output from `model_1` with `model_2[['BCTo']]` I see no difference. I'm on a Mac Air running Monterey with R 4.2.1 and recently installed version of pkg:gamlss. If you can reproduce this one whatever version of R, gamlss, and your unstated OS, then you should use output of `maintainer("gamlss")` to direct all these relevant details to the responsible address.